# How to create a non active dropdown with keybord focus

Tags: c#, windows

I want to create a dropdown control which should be inactive and have keyboard input focus. So I created a control as below.

```
public class DropDownEdit : UserControl
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    private const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
    private const int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
    private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
    private const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
    private const int WS_POPUP = unchecked((int)0x80000000);

    private TextBox text = new TextBox();

    public DropDownEdit()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(44, 68, 107);
        this.Controls.Add(text);
        this.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        this.Padding = new Padding(0);
        text.Multiline = true;
        text.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
        text.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.Style &= ~WS_CHILD;
            createParams.Style |= WS_POPUP;

            createParams.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
            createParams.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TOPMOST;
            createParams.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
            return createParams;
        }
    }

    public void ShowWindow(Point point)
    {
        text.Focus();
        this.Capture = true;
        SetParent(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero); 
        this.Location = point;
        Show();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseCaptureChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseCaptureChanged(e);
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

And when I am displaying the above dropdown window as below,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = this.PointToScreen(button1.Location);
        DropDownEdit window = new DropDownEdit();
        window.ShowWindow(new Point(point.X, point.Y + 20));
    }
}
```

The `Form1`  has a flickering while displaying `DropDownEdit`. I think `DropDownEdit` get activated and `Form1` loses its activation. How can I avoid this flickering in `Form1`?

NB:- I need input focus on `TextBox` in the dropdown control.

Comment: Do you have the `DoubeBuffered` property of `Form1` set to `True`?

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh Actually it is not a painting related flickering. Here flickering means my dropdown window becomes an active window even though it has `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` style. So `Form1` has a blink effect and nothing doing with `DoubeBuffered`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

While displaying my dropdown window it will receive activation and Windows will deactivate the main window. The fix for this is to send a `WM_NCACTIVATE` message to the parent to update its visual appearance without changing its activation status. 
The below code is updated in `DropDownEdit` class to solve my issue.

```
    private const int WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x86;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // The popup needs to be activated for the user to interact with it,
        // but we want to keep the owner window's appearance the same.
        if ((m.Msg == WM_NCACTIVATE) && !_activating && (m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // The popup is being activated, ensure parent keeps activated appearance
            _activating = true;
            SendMessage(this.Owner.Handle, WM_NCACTIVATE, (IntPtr) 1, IntPtr.Zero);
            _activating = false;
            // Call base.WndProc here if you want the appearance of the popup to change
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The flag _activating is just  a module level bool?